# unexpected jxs using bracket and &&

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What's wrong with this jsx?

```
return(
    {(item.min_price > 0 || item.max_price > 0) && 
        <div className="col-md-12">
            {this.renderPrice()}
    </div>}
);
```

I got unexpected token at line 2.

Comment: Remove the curly brackets {}

Comment: @OriDrori where?

Comment: The outer `{}` are not valid there (or rather their content is not valid). An object literal cannot contain arbitrary expressions. `{... && ...}` is simply not valid JavaScript. You might be thinking: "`{...}` are used to embed expressions in JSX" and that is true. But the outer `{}` are not inside JSX.

Comment: you should check condition first then return div, and also don't include {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `curly brackets` it will work.

```js
const item = {
 min_price: 10,
  max_price: 10

}

class Test extends React.Component {
  render(){
     return(
          (item.min_price > 0 || item.max_price > 0) && 
              <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div>Price</div>
              </div>
      );
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```